# Lining up labels in separate <div> elements

Tags: html, css

I don't have a lot of experience working on the front end, so I am trying to get better with it. One of the things I have read is that it is better to use  and CSS for layout instead of using tables. This what I am attempting to do, but I cannot figure out how to get things to line up properly.

For instance I get

> [Name]..[TextBox]
>  [Master Name]..[TextBox]

What I want is

> [Name]..............[TextBox]
>  [Master Name]..[TextBox]

Below is the HTML I have created. (Sorry for the awkwardness, Stack Overflow's code block is not working well for me. It is also not displaying the final closing div elements.)

```
 <div id="info1" style="background-color:#ffffff;float:left;width:100%;height:50px">
    <div id="Name" style="background-color: #ffffff; float: left;">
        <label for="txtName" style="display:inline;padding-right:1em;">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" style="width:150px;" />      
       <button id="btnSelect">...</button>
       </div>
</div>

    <div id="info2" style="background-color:#ffffff; float: left; width: 100%; height: 50px">
    <div id="masterName" style="background-color: #ffffff; float: left;">
        <label for="txtMasterName" style="display:inline;padding-right:1em;">Master Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtMasterName" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put all of your styles into a .css file

Comment: Thanks Billy. That is my end goal here, just haven't gotten that far yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When people say not to use tables for layout, they mean site layout.

it is still acceptable to use tables in situations such as this, or, say a checkout cart

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/1879895) and the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84986/1879895) on tables.

Comment: Thanks @Dave hope it helped. If you feel my answer answered your question don't forget to accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Make your labels inline-block and set a width for them. The width will create the column effect for you:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qXFLa/514/) to demonstrate the general idea.

Comment: Kinakuta, that example is using <FieldSet> elements. Should I be using those instead of <div>?

Comment: that depends on how the form is divided up - forms should use fieldsets, but you don't need a new fieldset for each label/input pairing - refer to MDN to learn more about fieldsets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset - ultimately the key point is to use inline-block and set widths for the labels to create the effect you want